# implement conditional variable wait() - atmoic unlock+sleep?

Tags: multithreading, operating-system, locking, conditional-variable

I'm trying to figure out an implementation of conditional variable:

```c
// suppose there is an internal wait_queue for threads to block on this cv.
void wait(Mutex mtx) {
  enqueue(wait_queue, current_thread);
  
  mtx.unlock();
  // notify() kicks in?
  sleep();

  // lock again after waken up.
  mtx.lock();
}

void notify() {
  wait_thread = dequeue(wait_queue);
  wake_up(wait_thread);
}
```

As the pseudo-code implies, it first added current thread to the cv internal wait queue, then released the external mutex and went to sleeping status.

My question is what if `notify()` kicked in before `sleep()`, and tried to wake up the waiting thread which had not yet truely be in sleep (so this `wake_up()` will be an no-op?), and then context switched back to `sleep()`. Will the wait thread then block forever?

In other words, is there an atmoic `[mutex.unlock() + sleep()]` operation at the system level, to make sure `wake_up`() can't kick in before sleep()?